# PHP access array within simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a SOAP request that is returning an array of IDs. For some reason, I am having trouble accessing the array within the SimpleXML element.

I did a vardump of the simplexml object:

```
die(var_dump($POList));
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { ["int"]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(5) "20622" [1]=> string(5) "20868" [2]=> string(5) "20880" [3]=> string(5) "20883" [4]=> string(5) "21034" [5]=> string(5) "21065" [6]=> string(5) "21136" [7]=> string(5) "21160" [8]=> string(5) "21202" [9]=> string(5) "21247" } }
```

And then a var dump of what I though would be the array:

```
die(var_dump($POList->int));
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "20622" }
```

How do I access this array?

Comment: If you're making Soap requests why wouldn't you use the built-in SOAP Client? There's even scripts out there that will generate the classes for you

Comment: @Cfreak Because SOAP Client doesnt seem to like this .net webservice. I've managed to get the request in soapclient, but the only way ive been able to parse the response is to grab the XML and put it through SimpleXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement` implements `Traversable`, so you should be able to do:

```
foreach( $POList->int as $el)
    echo $el;
```

Or possibly query the array from xpath:

```
$array = $POList->xpath( '/int')[0];
foreach( $array as $el)
    echo $el;
```

Comment: The second example did not work, but the first did allow me to iterate over the items and rebuild an array.

Comment: The syntax in that second example will only work in PHP 5.4 onwards, as previous versions will reject the combination of function and array syntax of the form `foo()[0]`.